# Pygame: Movement code doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, keyboard-events

I have a problem with character movement in pygame. 
What I want to do is to be able to hold a key down, and have the sprite move. But, I have to keep on tapping the key to make the sprite move. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here's my code:

```
key_state = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key_state [K_LEFT]:
   world.move(xx)
   doom.move(xx)
if key_state [K_RIGHT]:
   world.move(xx)
   doom.move(xx)
if key_state[K_UP]
   player.jump(jump_speed)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote from: http://pygame.org/ftp/contrib/input.html

> Keyboard Control
>
> The keyboard is probably the simplest input device. Keys are
>   represented by their key id value. The only real control you have over
>   the keyboard is setting repeat rates. By default, pygame sends a
>   single KEYDOWN and KEYUP event for every keypress. You can enable key
>   repeating with pygame.key.set_repeat(). The defaults are usually fine,
>   but you can fine tune the repeat behavior. When keys are repeating,
>   you will receive multiple KEYDOWN events for as long as the key is
>   held, and a final KEYUP when it is released.